# WPF - Binding decimal with StringFormat

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I want to display a decimal with a Binding in a TextBlock.

The problem occurs when the decimal is 0. Nothing is displayed in the TextBox.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Price, StringFormat={}{0:#,#.##}}"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
{0:#,0.##}
```

Note: As @ASh pointed out:
Values between 0.0 and 1.0 will be displayed as 0.X instead of .X (e.g. 0.31 instead of .31)

Comment: ther will be difference for values in (0,1) interval: `.31` vs `0.31`